# Hooking code into cookie-based login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In `ASP.NET Identity`, where do I 'hook in' to a successful log in, if I am using cookies?

What I want to do is simply fire off some code to check something, and I want that code to fire once for each user when they log in, whether that's from logging in via the `AccountController` or from automatic login via cookies auth...

I thought that `OnValidateIdentity` would be a good place, but that happens for every request, so not what I want.

My cookie auth setup:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<UserManager<User, long>, User, long>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20), 
                    regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                    getUserIdCallback: id => (long.Parse(id.GetUserId()))
                    )
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to log in when you already have the Auth cookie. You just sign in when you are missing the cookie or the cookie is expired. The cookie will be sent with every request and that is why OnValidateIdentity is triggered every time.

But you can hook up some logic in the AccountController Login (Post) method.

Also you can edit the cookie expiration time so the Login method is called more.

Comment: Cheers for the response, but what I want is to execute some code ONE TIME when a user logs in. I can't add that code to the session start because the user identity won't be set by then, so looking for a "user has logged in from cookie" hook seemed the obvious solution